# Can I put my buttons into a separate view?

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I am saving a picture of my base *UIView* via `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`.

I have not created a separate *UIImageview*, everything is in the same base view, including my buttons, therefore when I save the picture, it includes my buttons too.

Is there any way I can put the buttons in a separate view, so that they are still visible in the app, but do not appear in the picture that I save via `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`?

Comment: You can create any view hierarchy that your app needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried hiding the buttons with .isHidden just before you call UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum? Then re-enable them afterwards.

Alternatively you'd have to put the buttons on a separate view that's not part of the one you're saving.

Comment: Works fantastically, thank you. I set it back to false at the end of the function so they re-appear. Thanks!

Comment: While this works it's not ideal. What if you add more buttons or other views? It's just prone to mistakes. Better to organize your views better. Or at least put everything you might ever need to hide in one common parent view then you only ever need to hide/show that one view.